Kafka + Schema registry in .NET test containers: Failed to resolve kafka host
I'm trying to set up Kafka & Schema registry via TestContainers.
I've drafted a setup that manages to successfully spin up both containers, but struggle to consume from outside of the containers.
In particular, I'm trying to connect a kafka admin client. Some admin commands (see CALL 1 below) seem to get through fine. Others (see CALL 2) below fail, with this looking like the likely error:
[thrd:kafka:9092/1]: kafka:9092/1: Failed to resolve 'kafka:9092': Name of service not known (after 12ms in state CONNECT)
[thrd:app]: rdkafka#producer-1: kafka:9092/1: Failed to resolve 'kafka:9092': Name or service not known (after 12ms in state CONNECT))

I'm currently at a loss why that's happening. Can anyone spot an issue with my configuration?
My current setup is as follows:

  [Test]
   public async Test my_setup()
   {
      var network = new NetworkBuilder().WithName(Guid.NewGuid().ToString("D")).Build();
      await network.CreateAsync();

      var kafkaContainer = BuildKafkaContainer(network);
      await _kafkaContainer.StartAsync();

      var schemaRegistryContainer = BuildSchemaRegistryContainer(network);
      await _schemaRegistryContainer.StartAsync();

      var kafkaAdminClient = new AdminClientBuilder(new AdminClientConfig {
        BootstrapServers = kafkaContainer.GetBootstrapAddress(),
        SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocol.Plaintext,
      }).Build();

      // CALL 1: This call works fine and returns empty data as expected
      var meta = kafkaAdminClient.GetMetadata(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

      // CALL 2: This call does eventually times out, with the likely cause in the debug output:
      //
      // [thrd:kafka:9092/1]: kafka:9092/1: Failed to resolve 'kafka:9092': Name of service not known (after 12ms in state CONNECT)"
      // [thrd:app]: rdkafka#producer-1: kafka:9092/1: Failed to resolve 'kafka:9092': Name or service not known (after 12ms in state CONNECT))
      // .. messages repeating ..
      await KafkaAdminClient.CreateTopicsAsync(new[] { new TopicSpecification
      {
        Name = KafkaTopicName,
        ReplicationFactor = 1,
        NumPartitions = 1,
      }}, new CreateTopicsOptions
      {
        OperationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60),
        RequestTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60)
      });
   }

 private KafkaContainer BuildKafkaContainer(INetwork network)
    {
        return new KafkaBuilder()
            .WithImage("confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.5.2")
            .WithNetworkAliases("kafka")
            .WithNetwork(network)
            .WithEnvironment("KAFKA_LISTENERS", $"PLAINTEXT://kafka:{KafkaBuilder.KafkaPort},BROKER://0.0.0.0:{KafkaBuilder.BrokerPort}")
            .WithStartupCallback((container, ct) =>
            {
                // Same as the default WithStartupCallback implementation all the way up until...
                const char lf = '\n';
                var startupScript = new StringBuilder();
                startupScript.Append("#!/bin/bash");
                startupScript.Append(lf);
                startupScript.Append($"echo 'clientPort={KafkaBuilder.ZookeeperPort}' > zookeeper.properties");
                startupScript.Append(lf);
                startupScript.Append("echo 'dataDir=/var/lib/zookeeper/data' >> zookeeper.properties");
                startupScript.Append(lf);
                startupScript.Append("echo 'dataLogDir=/var/lib/zookeeper/log' >> zookeeper.properties");
                startupScript.Append(lf);
                startupScript.Append("zookeeper-server-start zookeeper.properties &");
                startupScript.Append(lf);

                // ... all the way up until here: We override KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS
                startupScript.Append($"export KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://kafka:{KafkaBuilder.KafkaPort},BROKER://{container.IpAddress}:{KafkaBuilder.BrokerPort}");

                // ... and back to copy & pasting the default implementation
                startupScript.Append(lf);
                startupScript.Append("echo '' > /etc/confluent/docker/ensure");
                startupScript.Append(lf);
                startupScript.Append("/etc/confluent/docker/run");
                return container.CopyAsync(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(startupScript.ToString()), KafkaBuilder.StartupScriptFilePath, Unix.FileMode755, ct);
            })
            .Build();
    }

    private IContainer BuildSchemaRegistryContainer(INetwork network)
    {
        return new ContainerBuilder()
            .WithImage("confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:7.5.2")
            .WithNetwork(network)
            .WithExposedPort(8081)
            .WithPortBinding(8081, true)
            .WithEnvironment("SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME", "schema-registry")
            .WithEnvironment("SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS", "http://0.0.0.0:8081")
            .WithEnvironment("SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS", $"PLAINTEXT://kafka:{KafkaBuilder.KafkaPort}")
            .WithWaitStrategy(Wait.ForUnixContainer().UntilMessageIsLogged("Server started, listening for requests..."))
            .Build();
    }


If anyone runs into the same issue in the future: I've managed to "solve" it by effectively keeping the default  config as is, but adding an extra third listener that schema registry can connect to:
new KafkaBuilder()
  // ...
  .WithEnvironment("KAFKA_LISTENERS", $"PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:{KafkaBuilder.KafkaPort},BROKER://0.0.0.0:{KafkaBuilder.BrokerPort},PLAINTEXT_EXTERNAL://kafka:9876")
  .WithEnvironment("KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP", "BROKER:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT")
  .WithStartupCallback((container, ct) =>
  {
    // ...
    startupScript.Append($"export KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://{container.Hostname}:{container.GetMappedPublicPort(KafkaBuilder.KafkaPort)},BROKER://{container.Hostname}:{KafkaBuilder.BrokerPort},PLAINTEXT_EXTERNAL://kafka:9876");
    // ...
  })

I'll leave the question open however as I'm still not sure why the initial approach did not work
